# RMI chat program in java - how to send mesage from client to client (not through the server)?

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I cannot get the client to send a message to another client without going through the server. It is an obligatory school project that should be implemented like that. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

*Server Interface:*

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public interface ChatServerInt extends Remote {
    public abstract void register(ChatClientInt inClient) throws RemoteException;
    public abstract ChatClientInt[] getClients() throws RemoteException;
    public void disconnect(ChatClientInt client) throws RemoteException;
}
```

*Server Implementation:*

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ChatServerImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatServerInt, Runnable {
    private ChatClientInt[] clientList;
    int counter = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> connectedClients; 
    /**
     * List of all registered remote clients. 
     */
    private List<ChatClientInt> clients = null; 

    /**
     * Construct an instance of the chat server. 
     */
    public ChatServerImp() throws RemoteException {
        // initialise the list of client objects.
        clients = new ArrayList<ChatClientInt>();
        connectedClients = new ArrayList<String>();
        clientList = new ChatClientInt[16];
    }

    /**
     * Register a chat client. 
     */
    public void register(ChatClientInt inClient) throws RemoteException {
        // perform registration. 
        synchronized(clients)
        {
            clients.add(inClient);
            clientList[counter++] =  inClient;
            inClient = new ChatClientImp();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < clients.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(inClient.getName()+ "has joined\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /**After registering, each client will request the list of connected users. 
     * Get a list of chat clients. 
     */
    public synchronized ChatClientInt[] getClients() throws RemoteException {
        // generate and return the list
        return clientList;
    }

    public void disconnect(ChatClientInt client) throws RemoteException {
        for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(client.getName() + "" + "has joined \n");
        }
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a random subset. Based on an implementation of D. Knuth's 
     * @return
     */
    private static <T> List<T> randomSample2(List<T> items, int m) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            int pos = i + rnd.nextInt(items.size() - i);
            T tmp = items.get(pos);
            items.set(pos, items.get(i));
            items.set(i, tmp);
        }
        return items.subList(0, m);
    }   

    /**
     * Run the server's main thread. The server should periodically 
     * iterate through all registered clients to find out if they 
     * are still alive. Any dead clients will be removed from the 
     * client list. 
     */

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            //System.out.println("waiting for client connection....\n");
            // sleep for a while
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                // iterate through all the clients we know. if we can't communicate with the client
                // then eliminate it else if we can communicate with the client then do nothing. 
                for(int i =0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        if(clients.get(i).getName()==null) {
                            clients.remove(clients.get(i).getName());
                            System.out.println("Disconnected clients:\n" + clients.get(i).getName());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (RemoteException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }           
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat server. 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //ChatServerInt server;
        try {
            String serverName = "rmi://localhost/ChatServer";
            // create an instance of the chat server
            //server = (ChatServerImp) new ChatServerImp();

            //Launch the registry - saves invoking it manually
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

            // register the instance with the RMIRegistry
            Naming.rebind(serverName, new ChatServerImp());

            //Naming.rebind(serverName, server);

            // create the server thread and start it
            //Thread t = new Thread(server).start();

            System.out.println("Server running.....\n");
        }
        catch(RemoteException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error binding the server to rmi");
        }
    }
}
```

*Message Interface:*

```java
import java.util.HashSet;

public interface MessageInt {
    /**
     * Add a chat recipient to the list of receivers
     * @param inClient
     */
    public abstract void addRecipient(ChatClientInt inClient);

    /**
     * Get the set of clients that have seen this message
     * @return
     */
    public abstract HashSet<ChatClientInt> getRecipients();

    /**
     * Get the message content.  
     * @return
     */
    public abstract String getContent();

    /**
     * Get an ID for a sender of the message
     * @return
     */
    public abstract String getSource();

}
```

*Message Implementation:*

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MessageImp implements MessageInt, Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2686034785384409672L;
    HashSet<ChatClientInt> clientSet = new HashSet<ChatClientInt>();

    String messageContent;
    String messageSource;

    public MessageImp(String inUser , String inMsg) {
        messageSource = inUser;
        messageContent = inMsg;
    }

    /**
     * Add a chat recipient to the list of receivers
     * @param inClient
     */
    public void addRecipient(ChatClientInt inClient) {
        synchronized(inClient) {
            clientSet.add(inClient);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of clients that have seen this message
     * @return
     */
    public HashSet<ChatClientInt> getRecipients() {
        return clientSet;   
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content.  
     * @return
     */
    public String getContent() {
        return messageContent;  
    }

    /**
     * Get an ID for a sender of the message
     * @return
     */
    public String getSource() {
        return messageSource;   
    }
}
```

*Client Interface:*

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ChatClientInt extends Remote {
    /**
     * Process a newly received message. 
     * 
     * @param inMessage
     */
    public void processMessage(MessageInt inMessage)throws RemoteException; 

    /**
     * Returns the name of the client. 
     */
    public String getName() throws RemoteException; 

    public boolean sendMessage(MessageInt inMessage) throws RemoteException;

}
```

*Client Implementation:*

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatClientImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatClientInt, Runnable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 74130345076834009L;

    private ArrayList <String> eventHistory = new ArrayList<String>();

    private HashSet<ChatClientInt> clientSet = new HashSet<ChatClientInt>();

    private List<ChatClientInt> clients;// = new ArrayList<ChatClientInt>();

    ChatClientInt[] listFromServer = new ChatClientInt[4];

    String clientName;
    String strMessage;
    MessageInt messageObj;
    ChatServerInt serverObj;


    public ChatClientImp() throws RemoteException {
        super();    
        clients = new ArrayList<ChatClientInt>();   
    }

    public void processMessage(MessageInt inMessage) throws RemoteException {   
        System.out.println("message:" + inMessage.getRecipients().toString() + inMessage.getSource() + inMessage.getContent() + "\n");      
    }


    public String getName() throws RemoteException {
        return clientName;
    }

    public synchronized boolean sendMessage(MessageInt inMessage) throws RemoteException {
        boolean success = false;    
        for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
            clients.get(i).processMessage(inMessage);
            inMessage.addRecipient(clients.get(i));
            success = true;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public void displayMessage(String displayName, String displayMsg) {
        Iterator<ChatClientInt> it = clientSet.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(displayName + displayMsg + "\n");
        }       
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String  userName = "";
        try {
            this.serverObj =(ChatServerInt) new ChatServerImp();            
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  Keep requesting until a name is submitted that is not already used.   
        // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name 
        // is done while locking the set of names.
        System.out.println("Please Enter a username\n");

        while(true) {           
            userName = scanner.nextLine();
            if(userName==null) {
                return;
            }   
            clientName = userName;
            try {
                serverObj.register(ChatClientImp.this);
                listFromServer = serverObj.getClients();
                clientSet.add(this);    
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Hi" + " " + clientName + " " + "enter your message\n");
            String msg = scanner.nextLine();
            if(msg.equals("exit")) {
                try {
                    serverObj.disconnect(this);
                    System.exit(0);
                } 
                catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//end if

            if((listFromServer.length) > 1) {
                System.out.println("list from client is" + " " + listFromServer.length + "going to try to send message.....\n");
                try {
                    this.messageObj = new MessageImp(userName,  msg);
                    boolean result = this.sendMessage(messageObj);
                    if(result) {
                        System.out.print("sending result is:" + result + "\n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("sending was not successful\n");
                    }
                } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Error tryiing to send message from the Run()\n");
                } 
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no one else logged on\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        String serverUrl= "rmi://localhost/ChatServer"; 
        try {
            ChatServerInt server = (ChatServerInt)Naming.lookup(serverUrl);
            Thread  thread = new Thread(new ChatClientImp());
            thread.start(); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me with any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: the problem is that your client thread should be using the server you lookup in the `main()` method, not instantiating one in the `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do that with RMI is if the clients are also RMI servers and send stubs to each other somehow.

Comment: Thanks. the clients are all registered with the rmi server. i dont know how to pass the stub or how to send the message from one client to another client without going through the server

Comment: @lyemwen The client can get the stub of another client from the server. It's just another remote method. But it won't work unless all the clients are behind the same firewall.